# Ourlink VER: Realtech USB Adaptor not Working

Tags: drivers, usb

I have a fresh install of 16.04 LTS on an HP Pavilion previously running Visa.  The Ourlink wireless dongle worked with Vista but not with 16.04.  (When I go to add a wireless network, no device is seen.)   I have the disk with driver "rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.14_13455.20150212_". I opened with package manager but am not sure it loaded.  It also has an install file that just seems to open when I run in terminal "install.sh"  I'm semi familiar with Ubuntu but no expert.

**lsusb** shows what is below.  Bus 002 Device 005 goes away when I unplug the dongle.

```
dan@Pavilion:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0111 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5111 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**Other wifi info**

```
    ########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 May 2017 15:43 PDT -0700

Booted last: 29 May 2017 00:00 PDT -0700

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Asus IPIBL-LB Motherboard [103c:2a6f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0111 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5111 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.153  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7e5:72be:181c:b1a3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:139342 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:82355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:183642869 (183.6 MB)  TX bytes:7890638 (7.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5045 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5045 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:487716 (487.7 KB)  TX bytes:487716 (487.7 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search surewest.net

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       872     1  0 09:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Asus IPIBL-LB Motherboard)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       a907b954-c6f5-3484-b170-a62ab9c8cfb2
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   a907b954-c6f5-3484-b170-a62ab9c8cfb2 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.153/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          surewest.net
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        server_name = ecosystem.home.cisco.com
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.153
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       domain_name = surewest.net
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       expiry = 1496161984
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       host_name = Pavilion
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[32]:                       requested_host_name = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7e5:72be:181c:b1a3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_domain_search = surewest.net.
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:2:3:9:5:5:<MAC address>
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:3:a4:98:7e:4b:7c:3b:cb:bc:6b:98:4:4c:56:a3:d0

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Los_Angeles (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do:

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU.git
cd rtl8812AU
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

You have compiled the driver for your current running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later one, also known as linux-image, re-compile:

```
cd  rtl8812AU
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

Comment: worked perfectly

Comment: I rebooted and the connection is now gone.  I can see wifi under network connections and there is what looks like a mac address.  Settings look good but it does not see any wireless signals.  Did I miss a step?  I rebooted the router and another system on wifi is working.

Comment: Rerunning the re-compile gets me a connection  again so am I missing some kind of save or load function?

Comment: *Another reboot and  it connects on its own so it is working but I'm not sure why*

Comment: I suspect that, once you got it compiled and did the many updates, one of the updates was a newer kernel version, also known as linux-image. They will always require a recompile as I explain above. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour